# How can I use a field from aggregate in a regex $match in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

A very simplified version of my use case is to find all posts beginning with the authors name, something like this:

```
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c4185be19da7e815cb18f59"), "name" : "User1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c4185be19da7e815cb18f5a"), "name" : "User2" }

db.posts.insert([
  {author : ObjectId("5c4185be19da7e815cb18f59"), text: "User1 is my name"},
  {author : ObjectId("5c4185be19da7e815cb18f5a"), text: "My name is User2, but this post doesn't start with it"}
]);
```

So I want to identify all posts that start with the authors name. I'm trying with an aggregate like this, but I don't know how to extract the user's name from the aggregate pipeline to use in a regex match:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "posts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "author",
      as: "post"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { "post.text": { $regex: "^" + name}}
  }
]).pretty();
```

The thing "name" here is not something defined, I need to extract the name  from the users collection entry from the previous step of the pipeline. For some reason I don't understand how to do that.

This is probably super simple and I'm definitely feeling thick as a brick here… Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BHqT6t8ALEX) using [**`$indexOfCP`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/)

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "posts",
    "let": { "authorId": "$_id", "name": "$name" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$ne": [{ "$indexOfCP": ["$text", "$$name"] }, -1] },
            { "$eq": ["$author", "$$authorId"] }
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "post"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Don't understand how this would help or why it would work. name is not defined, now it just fails straight away on the first match…? Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. name is from the "user" collection and I later want to match using regex against the post text.

Comment: Then please try to explain your question bit more

Comment: Added another paragraph to explain that "name" is something I'm trying to extract from the previous step of the aggregate.

Comment: Ah, seems to work in playground with 4+, but I'm unfortunately on 3.4.18: "arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { authorId: \"$_id\", name: \"$name\" } is type object""

But thanks, will upgrade soon!

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet What would be the case for type object? How regexp can be used for object type? MongoError: $indexOfCP requires a string as the first argument, found: object

Comment: @NaumanRafique Please ask a new question related to your specific problem. I will surely help you.

Comment: This would be more correct if the index of name is compared to 0 rather than -1 since the question was about “starts with” and not just exists within the string.